# How to read/write Java ASCII Characters value with XMLStreamReader?

Tags: java, ascii, xmlstreamreader, xml-encoding, xmlencoder

I'd like to use XMLStreamReader for reading a XML file which contains Horizontal Tab ASCII Codes `&#009;`, for example:

`<tag>foo&#009;bar</tag>`

and print out or write it back to another xml file.

Google tells me to set `javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing` to `true` in `XMLInputFactory`, but my test code below does not work as expected.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XMLStreamException {
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setProperty(factory.IS_COALESCING, true);

    System.out.println("IS_COALESCING supported ? " + factory.isPropertySupported(factory.IS_COALESCING));
    System.out.println("factory IS_COALESCING value is " +factory.getProperty(factory.IS_COALESCING));

    String rawString = "<tag>foo&#009;bar</tag>";
    XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(rawString));
    System.out.println("reader IS_COALESCING value is " +reader.getProperty(factory.IS_COALESCING));

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
    while (reader.hasNext())
    {
        reader.next();
        pw.print(reader.getEventType());
        if (reader.hasText())
            pw.append(' ').append(reader.getText());
        pw.println();
    }
}
```

The output is

```
IS_COALESCING supported ? true
factory IS_COALESCING value is true
reader IS_COALESCING value is true
1
4 foo   bar
2
8
```

But I want to keep the same Horizontal Tab 	 like:

```
IS_COALESCING supported ? true
factory IS_COALESCING value is true
reader IS_COALESCING value is true
1
4 foo&#009;bar
2
8
```

What am I missing here? thanks

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, the parsing part is correct - it's just not printed as you envision it. Your unicode encoding is interpreted by the XML reader as `\t` and represented accordingly in Java.

Using Guava's XmlEscapers, I can produce something similar to what you want to have:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XMLStreamException {
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, true);

        System.out.println("IS_COALESCING supported ? " + factory.isPropertySupported(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING));
        System.out.println("factory IS_COALESCING value is " + factory.getProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING));

        String rawString = "<tag>foo&#009;bar</tag>";
        XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(rawString));
        System.out.println("reader IS_COALESCING value is " + reader.getProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING));

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            reader.next();
            pw.print(reader.getEventType());
            if (reader.hasText()) {
                pw.append(' ').append(XmlEscapers.xmlAttributeEscaper().escape(reader.getText()));
            }
            pw.println();
        }
    }
```

The Output looks like this:

```
IS_COALESCING supported ? true
factory IS_COALESCING value is true
reader IS_COALESCING value is true
1
4 foo&#x9;bar
2
8
```

Some remarks to this:

- The library itself is marked as unstable, there might be other alternatives
- `\t` does not need to be escaped in XML content, thus I had to choose the attribute converter. While it works, there might be some side effects
- Is a 100%-copy of the content really required? Otherwise, I would suggest to let the XML libraries do their work and have them create the correct encoding.

  - If you really want to have a 1:1 copy, is it an option to specify the input as `CDATA`?